# What is difference between "Office SharePoint Server Search" and "Windows SharePoint Services Search "

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have MOSS 2007 environment with multiple WFE servers. can any one know what is difference between "Office SharePoint Server Search"  and "Windows SharePoint Services Search ".

Which service i have to start ?  If i have to Start "Office SharePoint Server Search" then what is the meaning of giving "Windows SharePoint Services Search " in Central Administration.

---Keshaw

Comment: I have the exact same question and can't believe no answers yet; guess everyone is busy installing 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, [Why does Sharepoint have two services? Office SharePoint Server Search and Windows SharePoint Services Help Search?](http://yiusan.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/why-does-sharepoint-have-two-services-office-sharepoint-server-search-and-windows-sharepoint-services-help-search/) sheds some light on this.

Personally, I do not understand the what is meant by the *Help system* and if our users are using it.

Anyway, the Windows SharePoint Services Search was the culprit in a serious performance issue and we rescheduled it to run in the early morning rather than each hour. We are thinking about switching it off completely. Our administrator has always reported that *Search* was only running at night, but that was Office SharePoint Server Search.